# XNA bounding spheres won't display in correct location

Tags: animation, xna

I am trying to get bounding spheres to display correctly for my models so I can see what is happening when I do collision tests.  I cannot get the bounding spheres to draw in the correct location.  The models look fine.  I believe the problem is in the transformation step for the bounding spheres.  The sphere itself is a simple .x file with a radius of 1 unit (in boundingSphereModel).  I then scale it to the actual mesh's bounding sphere radius.  I do have spheres with various radii but they all display in a clump at the feet of the player instead of over the various body parts.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
private void drawPlayer(Matrix viewMatrix, Player player)
{
    SkinnedModel skinnedModel = player.getModel();
    Matrix[] boneTransforms = new Matrix[skinnedModel.Model.Bones.Count];
    skinnedModel.Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(boneTransforms);

    Matrix transformationMatrix = player.getWorldTransformation();
    foreach (ModelMesh modelMesh in player.getMeshes())
    {
        if (drawBoundingSpheres)
        {
            int boneIndex = modelMesh.ParentBone.Index;
            Matrix boneTransform = boneTransforms[boneIndex];

            GraphicsDevice.RenderState.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
            Matrix scaleMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(modelMesh.BoundingSphere.Radius);
            Matrix worldMatrix = scaleMatrix * boneTransform * transformationMatrix;

            // loop through all bounding sphere's meshes, transforming & drawing them
            foreach (ModelMesh boundingSphereModelMesh in boundingSphereModel.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in boundingSphereModelMesh.MeshParts)
                {
                    BasicEffect basicEffect = (BasicEffect)meshPart.Effect;

                    basicEffect.World = worldMatrix;
                    basicEffect.View = viewMatrix;
                    basicEffect.Projection = cameraProjection;

                    // configure lighting
                    basicEffect.AmbientLightColor = new Vector3(0.1f);
                }
                boundingSphereModelMesh.Draw();
            }
            // done with bounding spheres; switch back to solid fill mode
            GraphicsDevice.RenderState.FillMode = FillMode.Solid;
        }

        // draw model mesh
        foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in modelMesh.MeshParts)
        {
            SkinnedModelBasicEffect basicEffect = (SkinnedModelBasicEffect)meshPart.Effect;

            basicEffect.World = transformationMatrix;
            basicEffect.Bones = player.getBones();
            basicEffect.View = viewMatrix;
            basicEffect.Projection = cameraProjection;

            basicEffect.Material.EmissiveColor = new Vector3(0.0f);
            basicEffect.Material.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0.8f);
            basicEffect.Material.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.3f);
            basicEffect.Material.SpecularPower = 8;
            basicEffect.NormalMapEnabled = false;
            basicEffect.SpecularMapEnabled = false;

            // configure lighting
            basicEffect.AmbientLightColor = new Vector3(0.1f);
            basicEffect.LightEnabled = true;
            basicEffect.EnabledLights = EnabledLights.Four;
            basicEffect.PointLights[0].Color = LIGHT_COLOR;
            basicEffect.PointLights[0].Position = COLOR0_POSITION;
            basicEffect.PointLights[1].Color = LIGHT_COLOR;
            basicEffect.PointLights[1].Position = COLOR1_POSITION;
            basicEffect.PointLights[2].Color = LIGHT_COLOR;
            basicEffect.PointLights[2].Position = COLOR2_POSITION;
            basicEffect.PointLights[3].Color = LIGHT_COLOR;
            basicEffect.PointLights[3].Position = COLOR3_POSITION;
        }

        modelMesh.Draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also looking for a way to draw bounding spheres, and have not found one yet. Because of that, I cannot help you with how to draw them. However I am fairly sure that the bounding spheres don't have meshes or anything like that. You have to draw them some other (more complicated) way.